# TWebBrowser: Disable all security restrictions

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

I am using a TWebBrowser component in Delphi 10.2 which is imported from the SHDocVW_TLB type library.

I want to use this web browser to browse local files and files in a trusted environment. But I noticed that an AJAX call from a local file (more precisely: Custom HTML content I have loaded into the browser component using [this code](https://www.viathinksoft.de/svn/fastphp/trunk/WebBrowserUtils.pas)) to LAN or WAN is not possible due to the security restrictons.

My goal is to disable all security restrictions (I am aware of the risks) for this web browser control.

Not sure if there are other ways, but I think I have to create a custom IInternetSecurityManager. During my research I found [this document by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537182(v=vs.85).aspx) , and it explains how to write such a SecurityManager.
But nowhere I can find how to "insert/overwrite" this custom IInternetSecurityManager into my TWebBrowser control.

What do I need to do to completely disable all security restrictions?
Thank you for any hint!

Comment: Take a look at [EmbeddedWB's security manager](https://github.com/ghquant/Delphi-EmbeddedWB/blob/master/Source/SecurityManager.pas) and how it's used by the browser control.

Comment: @Victoria The file SecurityManager.pas contains the class implementation `TSecurityManager = class(TComponent, IInternetSecurityManager)` , but in the code I cannot find an actual use of any TSecurityManager object, except for Source/EwbReg.pas, which only registers the component. So I still don't know how to tell TWebBrowser to use a custom security manager implementation.

Comment: You need to handle OnQueryService and when it asks about an IInternetSecurityManager service, create yours and return it to the caller.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Thank you for this hint. That sounds logical. But I am using the normal TWebBrowser, not TEmbeddedWB . Is there a similar method for that?

Comment: I think I found it: `webbrowser1.ServiceQuery := EmbeddedWBQueryService;`  . I will check it out!

Answer (score 6):

The answer is in the same [MSHTML documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537182.aspx) that you linked to in your question:

> Applications Hosting the WebBrowser Control or MSHTML
>
> The [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) or MSHTML hosts could create a security manager (by implementing the [`IInternetSecurityManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130.aspx) interface) that handles the URL actions and policies that are important to the host. Other URL actions and policies would be passed to the default security manager so it could handle them appropriately. The [`IInternetSecurityMgrSite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537098.aspx) interface would be used to handle Windows-related information from the component so that the customized security manager could handle any user interface it required.
>
> **To create a customized security manager, the component must implement the [`IInternetSecurityManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130.aspx) interface**. Any methods or URL actions that the customized security manager needs the default security manager to act on should return [`INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145.aspx).
>
> Security Warning:  Implementing [`IInternetSecurityManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130.aspx) methods incorrectly can compromise the security of your application. Any methods or URL actions that the customized security manager needs the default security manager to act on should return [`INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145.aspx). If a method does not override default behavior and returns an HRESULT indicating success, the action is unhandled and can put users at risk for an elevation of privilege attack. You should review [Security Considerations: URL Security Zones API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537019.aspx) before continuing.
>
> **The component must also implement an object that supports the [`IOleClientSite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693706.aspx) interface when embedding either the [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) or MSHTML.**
>
> The following steps occur for a URL action.
>
> 1. MSHTML uses [`CoCreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615.aspx) to create an instance of the [Internet Security Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537026.aspx).
> 2. The [Internet Security Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537026.aspx) calls the [`QueryInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521.aspx) method on MSHTML to get its [`IServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678965.aspx) interface. **MSHTML then calls the `QueryInterface` method on the [`IOleClientSite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693706.aspx) interface to get the `IServiceProvider` interface**.
> 3. **[`IServiceProvider::QueryService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678966.aspx) is called to get an [`IInternetSecurityManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130.aspx) interface**. The component then passes a pointer to its implementation of `IInternetSecurityManager` to the [Internet Security Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537026.aspx).
> 4. Calls from MSHTML to the [`IInternetSecurityManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130.aspx) methods are passed to the custom security manager from the default [Internet Security Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537026.aspx).
> 5. If the method called returns [`INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775145.aspx), the default implementation of [`IInternetSecurityManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130.aspx) is used to resolve the call. Otherwise, the result from the custom security manager is returned.
> 6. The [Internet Security Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537026.aspx) returns the result back to MSHTML.

So, first you need to write a class that implements the `IInternetSecurityManager` interface.

Second, fortunately `TOleControl` (which `TWebBrowser` derives from) has implemented the `IOleClientSite` and `IServiceProvider` interfaces since at least Delphi 2006, so all you need to do is assign a handler to its public [`ServiceQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.OleCtrls.TOleControl.ServiceQuery) event, and when MSHTML calls `IServiceProvider.QueryService()` looking for `IInternetSecurityManager`, you can return an instance of your custom security manager class.

For older Delphi versions, you can manually provide an `IOleClientSite` object to `TWebBrowser` by query its `DefaultInterface` property for the [`IOleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542709.aspx) interface, and then call the [`IOleObject.SetClientSite()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684013.aspx) method.  An example of this is demonstrated in the following article:

[How to customise the TWebBrowser user interface (part 3 of 6)](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=18&part=3)

Providing `TWebBrowser` with a custom `IOleClientSite` is how you can also provide your own custom [`IDocHostUIHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260.aspx), [`IDocHostUIHandler2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753275.aspx), [`IDocHostShowUI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753269.aspx), and [`ICustomDoc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753272.aspx) objects to MSHTML (MSHTML does not query for them using `IServiceProvider`, so they will not trigger the `TWebBrowser.ServiceQuery` event).  These interfaces are at the root of most [WebBrowser Customization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041.aspx) options, as described on MSDN:

> The mechanism for [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) customization is designed to be automated when a container provides support for ActiveX controls. **Whenever the WebBrowser Control is instantiated, it attempts to find `IDocHostUIHandler`, `IDocHostUIHandler2` and `IDocHostShowUI` implementations from the host, if they are available. The WebBrowser Control does this by a [`QueryInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521.aspx) call on the host's [`IOleClientSite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693706.aspx) interface**.
>
> This architecture works automatically for an application that implements an [`IOleClientSite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693706.aspx) interface and that passes an `IOleClientSite` pointer to the [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) through the browser's [`IOleObject::SetClientSite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684013.aspx) method.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. I have managed to replace the IInternetSecurityManager ( https://pastebin.com/288rRLi6 ), and now I could set all pages to the same zone. I also permitted all ProcessUrlAction and QueryCustomPolicy requests with "Allow". However, it doesn't work as expected. I expected all security limitations to be gone. But that doesn't seem the case. Cross-domain-requests do not work (file:// to https://) , and AJAX queries from a "file://" page to a "file://" page do not work either . :-( Is there anything I have missed or what I can do to lower the security more?

Comment: Maybe that is because you are forcing all URLs to be in the "Internet" zone only. That is certainly not a good idea for local content that should probably be in the "Local" or "Trusted" zone instead. See [Security Considerations: URL Security Zones API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537019(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Comment: I have tried out all zones, but it doesn't work. As soon as I try to call a local file via AJAX/JavaScript, I get an "Access denied" error. About the other scenario, cross-domain-queries, the problem is the restriction "Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page", but I was hoping that the security manager can override that rule, too. But with my AJAX scenario, file:// calls file:// , so I don't understand why there is no access.